# Route never hits properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

I have this method in a controller named SecureAPI. The route looks pretty simple, but whatever I do I can't seem to invoke it.

Method:

```
[Route("SecureAPI/SetOrderAsProcessedAsync/{uid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SetOrderAsProcessedAsync([FromRoute(Name = "uid")] Guid uid)
{
    Order order = await _exp.Order(uid);
    _db.Update(order);

    order.IsProcessed = true;
    order.DateProcessed = DateTime.Now;

    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Orders", "Secure");
}
```

Link:

```
<a asp-controller="SecureAPI" asp-action="SetOrderAsProcessedAsync" asp-all-route-data="@(new { uid = Model.Order.UId }.ToRouteData())" class="btn-antan action flex-center-center"><icon awesome="Lock" />&nbsp;Set as processed</a>
```

Which generates this link:

```
http://localhost:5294/SecureAPI/SetOrderAsProcessedAsync?uid=f345f4d2-b184-4652-bd1b-78cc2f28aaff
```

ToRouteData extension:

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> ToRouteData(this object obj)
{
    IDictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (IObjectPropertyModel prop in obj.GetProperties())
    {
        result.Add(prop.Name, prop.Value);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your route expects to receive the `uid` as part of route (parameter), but with `asp-all-route-data`, it will populate the route with query parameter.

Comment: @YongShun if the route is found, the link will be correctly generated. at least that's my experience

Answer (score 1):

The [`asp-all-route-data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-8.0#asp-all-route-data) will interpret and flatten the dictionary data into the query string. Your route action expects to receive the `uid` as the route parameter.

Thus, the routes from the Controller action and the link generated from the anchor helper are not matched.

You have to use [`asp-route-{value}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-8.0#asp-route-value) to interpret the value as a route parameter.

```
asp-route-uid="@Model.Order.UId"
```

```
<a asp-controller="SecureAPI" asp-action="SetOrderAsProcessedAsync" asp-route-uid="@Model.Order.UId" class="btn-antan action flex-center-center"><icon awesome="Lock" />&nbsp;Set as processed</a>
```

In the middleware pipeline, you need to specify the route constraint for your route: `Controller = "SecureAPI", action = "SetOrderAsProcessedAsync"` and place it before the default route constraint.

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "SecureAPI",
        pattern: "SecureAPI/SetOrderAsProcessedAsync/{uid}",
        defaults: new { controller = "SecureAPI", action = "SetOrderAsProcessedAsync" });

    // Default route
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

[image]

Comment: I changed it to asp-route-uid="@Model.Order.UId", but still same issue. If I alter the generated URL and removes the query, it hit's the method just fine. so there's something about the generated URL

Comment: I can't spend more time on this so I set it to <a href="/SecureAPI/SetOrderAsProcessedAsync/@Model.Order.UId" class="btn-antan action flex-center-center"><icon awesome="Lock" />&nbsp;Set as processed</a>

Comment: Apologize for the previous answer, I fixed it. Ya, your answer works without need to configure the route constraint.

Comment: it's weird, I must have made 100 links just like this without any issues. but yeah, at least now it works. thanks!